# Were fermions ever massless?

Tags: cosmology, standard-model, fermions, higgs

In a discussion of the Standard model and Higgs mechanism it was claimed that [accordingly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction#Lagrangian):

> "During an early phase of the cosmos all fermions were massless."

I wonder whether this claim can be challenged. Therefore the following more detailed questions:

1. Is it fair to say that, according to the standard model, the mass of any fermion is an "effective mass", that it may vary depending on the Higgs field strength, and that it must necessarily vanish only if the Higgs field strength is exactly zero?
2. Is it fair to say that under conditions "*during an early phase of the cosmos*" (or: at sufficiently large temperature, density, ...), and while fermions are present, the Higgs field strength is not necessarily exactly zero?

Comment: The Higgs field and the mechanism of symmetry breaking are a quantum mechanical effect. It is not a continuous field distortion . As energy is increased a value is arrived where symmetry is unbroken and what is the higgs field below breaking energy is zero mass goldstone bosons above the breaking energy http://www.physics.indiana.edu/~dermisek/QFT_09/qft-II-6-4p.pdf .

Comment: @anna v: "_As energy is increased a value is arrived where symmetry is unbroken_" -- Is there some expression for this "_breaking energy_" value, perhaps in terms of parameter $\lambda$, or others?   $\, \, \, \,$   "_what is the higgs field below breaking energy is zero mass goldstone bosons above the breaking energy_" -- Fine; but does that have any consequence for the possibility of the Lagrange function containing "fermion mass terms"? (If the nice lecture notes that you linked address these questions, I'd appreciate some more specific clues ...)

Comment: Unfortunately I am an experimentalist, not a theorist, and retired fro the last ten years . I can get the gist of a theoretical argument when scanning equations but I cannot presume to point at the exact parametrization. If you are really that much interested you should invest in learning the mathematics and spend the time in deciphering the details of the change in the Lagrangian. As an experimentalist I trust the interpretation theorists give, enough to spend a working life in experiments. People who want to change interpretations have to devote time to learning the stuff first.

Comment: If you go to the link I gave you and search for "fermion" you will see the second item is the mass for the fermions, which depends on  values of the broken lagrangian. Trust means that one trusts that the theorist making these mathematical claims is better than me in maths and correct. It has worked well up to now.

Comment: This talk might help: http://hep.uchicago.edu/~pilcher/p463/Old/Lecture08%20Higgs.bw.pdf . It is the vacuum expectation value of the Higgs field that at very high energies goes to 0 and the coupling to the particles which gives their masses depends on this v.

Comment: Look at the potential illustrations of the last link.  It is a choice in the model to have a negative value for mu**2. This is what makes the original vacuum unstable. I think the cosmological argument goes as follows:At the first moments of the universe the energy density is large and the vacuum expectation value of the field that becomes the Higgs field is zero sitting at a metastable point (figure).  A random fluctuation as the universe expands/cools can break the symmetry choosing one non zero vacuum expectation and after that the universe is in a broken symmetry mode.

Comment: The reason for choosing a model where all masses are the same and 0 at high energies is an experimental one, due to the observation that all measured coupling constants seem to come to a common value at very high energies. http://www.clab.edc.uoc.gr/materials/pc/proj/running_alphas.html . Thus the unified model should have zero masses at those high energies ( at least constant) but display the masses we measure at our energies.

Comment: add atleast a single constant

Comment: @anna v: "_the coupling to the particles which gives their masses depends on this v_" -- That's sensible as long as $v$ is non-zero (such as in the "vacuum state") and the "Yukawa term" may be written as $-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} y (v + H) \bar{\mathscr{E}}\mathscr{E} := -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} y v (1 + \frac{H}{v}) \bar{\mathscr{E}}\mathscr{E} := -m_e (1 + \frac{H}{v}) \bar{\mathscr{E}}\mathscr{E}$. (Notation of Dermisek's notes p. 365; cmp. p. 15 of the linked "_talk_" as well.) But if $v = 0$ ? Then the "effective mass" is apparently $m = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} y H$. Therefore my question 1. (To be contd.)

Comment: @anna v: "_I think the cosmological argument goes as follows: At the first moments of the universe the energy density is large and the vacuum expectation value of the field that becomes the Higgs field is zero sitting at a metastable point (figure)._" Is there a reason or evidence that the field "_sat_ in the center of the Mexican hat", and not (at the same "_large energy density_") "at the rim"? (My question 2.) Also, in case $v = 0, H = 0$: is there any reason or evidence that fermions had been present at that moment/state at all? (To be contd.)

Comment: @anna v: "_The reason for choosing a model where all masses are the same and 0 at high energies is an experimental one, due to the observation that all measured coupling constants seem to come to a common value at very high energies._" Is such an argument perhaps being made for the "Yukawa couplings" "$y$", "$y'$", "$y''$" (cmp. Dermisek's notes p. 380) as well? And does this really force the Fermion masses not just to be equal, but to vanish?  (The CERN tutorial that you linked doesn't seem to address this ...)

Comment: you will have to grab the attention of a theorist to get clear answers to these questions . I think the equal mass for all can be translated to zero by an allowable transformation. The point I am making is that it is a successful model, depending on a minus sign in the potential. successful up to now, in its predictions. The successes in describing and predicting the data are the reason for the model assumptions.

Comment: @anna v: Well - thanks for your suggestions. And thanks for submitting them as comments instead as a (would be-) answer; thereby perhaps improving the chances of my question yet grabbing the attention of contributors who ... would address it authoratively, based on self-evident principles.